# Time series events using recharts bar graph?

Tags: reactjs, recharts

Is it possible to create a time series of events using horizontal bar chart with recharts?

I'm having trouble figuring out how to do this with recharts, where parts of the bar can sometimes be disconnected/empty.

A sample data payload would be something like this:

```
[
  {
    "from": "2023-04-30T00:00:00.000Z",
    "to": "2023-05-01T00:00:00.000Z",
    "message": "Code Freeze"
  },
  {
    "from": "2023-05-05T00:00:00.000Z",
    "to": "2023-05-10T00:00:00.000Z",
    "message": "Mother's Day Sale"
  },

  {
    "from": "2023-05-10T00:00:00.000Z",
    "to": "2023-05-15T00:00:00.000Z",
    "message": "Holiday Party"
  },
]
```

I want a horizontal bar chart where each bar represents something like a team, and the axis going from left to right will represent calendar days (not sure if this is still called X axis when we flipped this graph horizontally). And when I hover over each interval, it will display the message as a tooltip. Also, if possible, the intervals will be alternating in colors.

Would this be possible using recharts?

An example would be something like this: http://software.es.net/react-timeseries-charts/#/example/outages